# SQL Server Query to pull/updating the missing data from Previous months value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a two tables table Rev and Table Cost from both these tables are common column is Product ID and Tdate (Month/Year) for join.

from Table Rev I need to pull the cost from Table Cost table, however, if the cost is not found for the particular month then it should check for the previous month and bring that cost for that product. Like that it should check till last 6 months (looping) if the cost is not available and get the latest cost whichever is available for latest 6 months from that date.

However I am not able to get any idea how to solve it, Please help.

```
REV
Product ID  Transaction Date    Output should be
101         3/5/2018        16.8
101        3/24/2018        16.8
101        4/10/2018        16.8
101        5/30/2018        7.6
101        6/25/2018        14.3
102         1/1/2019        30.11
102         2/4/2019        30.11
102        2/11/2019        30.11
103        2/17/2019        6.62
103         2/25/2019       6.62
103        3/24/2019        6.62
103        3/30/2019        6.62
```

for the REV table I need to bring the cost based on PROD ID and Month/Year Match, if not available it should check for last 6 months backdate and bring the cost latest available month.

```
Cost
Product ID  PCR Period  Cost
101           Jan-18    16.8
101           May-18    7.6
101           Jun-18    14.3
101           Jul-18    301.88
101           Aug-18    6.62
101           Nov-18    0.01
102           Dec-18    6.62
102           May-18    47.95
102           Jun-18    79.8
102           Jul-18    3.49
102           Jan-19    30.11
103           Mar-19    102.11
```

Let me know if you need any futher details

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Using SQL Server

Comment: Is "PCR Period" a varchar?

Comment: Yes, it has only MOnth and Year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be close to what you're after

```
select r.id, r.td, (
    select top 1 c.cost from cost c
    where c.id = r.id
    and datediff(day, CAST('01-' + c.td AS datetime), r.td) >= 0
    order by CAST('01-' + c.td AS datetime) desc
) as cost
from rev r
```

EXAMPLE SCRIPT:

```
declare @REV table (id int, trandate datetime)

insert into @REV (id, trandate) values (101, '3/5/2018')
insert into @REV (id, trandate) values (101, '3/24/2018')
insert into @REV (id, trandate) values (101, '4/10/2018')
insert into @REV (id, trandate) values (101, '5/30/2018')
insert into @REV (id, trandate) values (101, '6/25/2018')
insert into @REV (id, trandate) values (102, '1/1/2019')
insert into @REV (id, trandate) values (102, '2/4/2019')
insert into @REV (id, trandate) values (102, '2/11/2019')
insert into @REV (id, trandate) values (103, '2/17/2019')
insert into @REV (id, trandate) values (103, '2/25/2019')
insert into @REV (id, trandate) values (103, '3/24/2019')
insert into @REV (id, trandate) values (103, '3/30/2019')

declare @COST table (id int, pcr varchar(20), cost float)

insert into @COST (id, pcr, cost) values (101, 'Jan-18', 16.8)
insert into @COST (id, pcr, cost) values (101, 'May-18', 7.6)
insert into @COST (id, pcr, cost) values (101, 'Jun-18', 14.3)
insert into @COST (id, pcr, cost) values (101, 'Jul-18', 301.88)
insert into @COST (id, pcr, cost) values (101, 'Aug-18', 6.62)
insert into @COST (id, pcr, cost) values (101, 'Nov-18', 0.01)
insert into @COST (id, pcr, cost) values (102, 'Dec-18', 6.62)
insert into @COST (id, pcr, cost) values (102, 'May-18', 47.95)
insert into @COST (id, pcr, cost) values (102, 'Jun-18', 79.8)
insert into @COST (id, pcr, cost) values (102, 'Jul-18', 3.49)
insert into @COST (id, pcr, cost) values (102, 'Jan-19', 30.11)
insert into @COST (id, pcr, cost) values (103, 'Mar-19', 102.11)

select r.id, r.trandate, (
    select top 1 c.cost from @cost c
    where c.id = r.id
    and datediff(day, CAST('01-' + c.pcr AS datetime), r.trandate) >= 0
    order by CAST('01-' + c.pcr AS datetime) desc
) as cost
from @rev r
```

RESULTS:

101 2018-03-05 16.8

101 2018-03-24 16.8

101 2018-04-10 16.8

101 2018-05-30 7.6

101 2018-06-25 14.3

102 2019-01-01 30.11

102 2019-02-04 30.11

102 2019-02-11 30.11

103 2019-02-17 NULL

103 2019-02-25 NULL

103 2019-03-24 102.11

103 2019-03-30 102.11

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, but problem here is it's taking only one cost across the product irrespective of cost exist or not

Comment: my requirement here is if cost exists, it should take that cost. If not exist if should look for previous month cost to bring the cost... like that it should check till 6 months back if cost not available for previous months

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a sample script and results. If you run the script in SQL you will get the results, which very much match your required results from the question (apart from product Id 103 which looks like you've make a mistake on as 6.62 is against product 102 in your cost table). So I'm confused what you want..

Comment: It most of the cases working... but couple thing to ask you why FEB we have null for two records and other two having cost? Irrespective of Day if I have the cost for FEB in Cost table then it should take that cost ignoring day.

Comment: also my join should be more over both prod id and monthyear from both the tables... would be possible

Comment: Can you update your question with the correct data you expect for 103?

Comment: The reason you have 2 NULLS is that you have transactions from Feb in your REV table, but no matching COST data for that product until March.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.PRODUCT_ID
      ,A.TRANSACTION_DATE
      ,(
            SELECT TOP 1 X.COST
            FROM COST X
            WHERE X.PRODUCT_ID = A.PRODUCT_ID
              AND X.PCR_PERIOD < = A.TRANSACTION_DATE
              AND X.PCR_PERIOD > DATEADD(MONTH,-6,A.TRANSACTION_DATE)
            ORDER BY X.PCR_PERIOD DESC
    ) AS COST
FROM REV A
```

Answer (score 0):

Written using Outer Apply and assuming PCR Period is a date:

```
SELECT REV.[Product ID], REV.[Transaction Date], LastCost.[Cost]
FROM REV
OUTER APPLY
(
SELECT TOP 1 Cost.Cost
FROM Cost
WHERE Cost.[Product ID]= REV.[Product ID]
AND Cost.[PCR Period] BETWEEN dateadd(month,-6,REV.[Transaction Date]) and REV.[Transaction Date]
ORDER BY Cost.[PCR Period] DESC
) AS LastCost
```

Comment: Thanks, but it giving one value for all the months, my output value should change where ever is having null, otherwise it should pick the respective month value